# Moving MySQL table data into new table on a schedule

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been assigned a task that can be solved by having a regularly scheduled movement of data from one table to another table on a MySQL server, and I'm a bit overwhelmed because I'm still new at this and don't even know the terminology I should be looking into. I want to migrate data that is more than 30 days old into the new table.

So basically, I would want a query like the one below to run every day at some specified time.

```
INSERT INTO tableB (columnA, columnB, columnC)
SELECT (columnA, columnB, columnC)
FROM tableA
WHERE created_on < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 day);

DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE created_on < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 day);

COMMIT;
```

So my question is, how would I go about setting that up?

Comment: What you need is to create an event (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html). It will run as often as you need - you already have query.

Comment: thanks! this looks like the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was posted as a comment, but anyway what I had to do was to use the Event Scheduler with something like this:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT archive_old_messages
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS curdate() 
    DO BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tableB (columnA, columnB, columnC)
    SELECT (columnA, columnB, columnC)
    FROM tableA
    WHERE created_on < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 day);

    DELETE FROM tableA
    WHERE created_on < DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL -30 day);
        END |

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create SQL job here and write your logic.

Regards

Abdul

Answer (score 0):

The second delete statement not working

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).